# how to insert value in single column for multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

I have registration table with different fields. I have thousands of records in that table. But now I want to add one column called 'gender' to that table. So How Do I insert values for previous thousands of records in the table??

Answer (score 2):

Either use a default value for your new column or add a value afterwards with an update statement.

So either

```
alter table your_table
add column gender char(1) default '-'
```

or

```
update your_table
set gender = '-'
where gender is null
```

Either way setting a gender to a default value is rather bad since this is a boolean condition which is wrong setting it for all records to a certain value.

Comment: can you explain with example??

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87e2a/1)

Adding column:

```
alter table table_name add column gender char(1)
```

updating all values:

```
update table_name set gender = 'M'
```